# lambda expression on interface in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, lambda, interface, kotlin

I'm converting a project in Java to Kotlin and I'm surprise that interface made the code heavier in Kotlin than in Java.

**Example**: 
I want to set the onBackPressListener in MainActivity from MyFragment.

File 1: MainActivity, File 2: MyFragment, File 3: OnBackPressedListener (Interface)

File 1 in Java, File 2 in Kotlin, File 3 in Java:

```
activity.setOnBackPressed { /* Do something */ }
```

File 1 in Kotlin, File 2 in Kotlin, File 3 in Java:

```
activity.setOnBackPressed(OnBackPressedListener { /* Do something */ })
```

File 1 in Kotlin, File 2 in Kotlin, File 3 in Kotlin:

```
activity.setOnBackPressed(object: OnBackPressedListener {
            override fun onBackPressed() {
                /* Do something */
            }
        })
```

Is it possible to have the 3 files in Kotlin and use lambda to set the listener ? 
(This is so frustrating to get more code in Kotlin..)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lambda version works only when kotlin interop with java because `SAM Conversions`, see [the official documents](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin
>   has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into
>   implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore
>   unsupported.

So if you want use lambda to set the listener with pure kotlin, you can define your `listener` and `setOnBackPressed` method like this:

```
var listener: (() -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnBackPressed(l: () -> Unit) {
    listener = l
}
```

then invoke it by:

```
listener?.invoke()
```

Comment: What does `invoke` actually do?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky since lambdas in kotlin are compiled into Function class objects with only invoke() method inside - invoke() just execute lambda block. Usually we just write lambda() which is same as lambda.invoke(). But with nullable lambdas we have to use question mark for null safety

Comment: Would `inline` and `crossinline` play any role on this particular execution?

Answer (score 6):

You use Java style while use Kotlin =)

If you really want to use `OnBackPressedListener` you can just wrap it in `inline` function, like:

```
inline fun backPress(crossinline action:()->Unit):OnBackPressedListener {
    return object: OnBackPressedListener {
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

And then just set listener

```
activity.setOnBackPressed(backPress {  
/* Do something */
})
```

Comment: What does `crossinline action` do?  And why do we have to create a whole new object...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky we create a new object only because author of question wanted to use it. Crossinline just restricts to use "return" in inlined lambda because it can finish wrong function

Comment: So your `crossinline` returns nothing?